# JVM and Oracle Database in different time zones

Tags: java, oracle, timezone

JVM timezone is different from my database timezone(1 hour apart).

Is there something obviously wrong with the below pseudo code. I have a process which updates rows which haven't been updated for over an hour.

**Pseudo Code**

```
while(true){
// Pick rows which were not updated in the last hour

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from data where  refresh_date<sysdate-(60/1440) and rownum <50");
// Update refreshed_date of each row which is going to be updated
//(the ones which were picked using the above query)
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("update data set refresh_date=sysdate where id =?");
//then update the actual row
}
```

Why I'm asking this?

The process is stuck with the same set of 50 rows.

```
select to_char(refresh_date,'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi') from data;
```

gives me the JVM time which suggests that the update query is using the JVM time. Does select work the same way or does it pick the database time?

Comment: Use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`...

Comment: Obviously the database will use the database's time zone. That doesn't mean there isn't any conversion going between the systems. Hence GMT all the things.

Comment: @Dave - but then why is the update statement updating the database with the JVM time?

Comment: it sounds like your nls parameters are not set correctly.